# Two variations of wordpress pages (Like multi-lingual plugins)

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently developing a theme for Wordpress site which needs to have two versions of every page. The case is that the pages should differ whether browsing as one type of customer(b2b) or another(b2c). This should be controlled by a url variable.

An example of what i am trying to achieve.

```
www.domain.com?version=b2b - b2b frontpage
www.domain.com?version=b2c - b2c frontpage
www.domain.com - Fallback b2b frontpage
```

In the admin area the best solution would be having those two different frontpages connected like when using WPML or other multilingual plugins (even though i am not searching for a language plugin).

I have tried to google this case with no luck and all i cand find is the language plugins.

Looking forward for your help. I am really stuck :)

Comment: do you mean you want a plugin already made that does that? Or the way to do this when coding your own theme? (note that the first question might be a bit out of this site bounds)

Comment: I am currently coding my own theme so i am open for coding it or using a ready plugin. Updated question

Comment: it was more a rethoric questions for future readers, as i'm a bit out of time this moment. I know no plugin for this, as a start, here is [a link for adding query params in wordpress](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/). I once used to solve this problem for woocommerce by creating an element for each version, with a custom field to be able to declare its corresponding other version. A bit crappy but it was in a hurry, and for a site admined by the company (not really good for a client admined)

Comment: Hi Kaddath - Yeah I’ve considered using a custom field with the id/slug of the corresponding page but this opens up for some new issues:

- duplicate content: a frontpage would be accessible from both pages permalinks which might be bad SEO-wise (the url-variable trick should avoid the frontpages to show up as more than one)

- In the admin area under pages it would not be visible which pages are connected with each other.

But thank you so much for your advise :)

Comment: yes the SEO syntax is important here, but you shouldn't have problems if you declare one of the 3 as canonical, and if you find a syntax that corresponds for your attribute 'b2b/b2c', declare the others as `rel="alternate"`. Each one will have a separate url. For the admin part, we admined ourselves, so it was allright, but for a client, a plugin would be a good idea to make the link between them, a bit more tricky